# Internet Explorer menu options grayed out when debugging Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, debugging

I'm at a loss on this, I have a problem that pops up maybe 50% of the time when debugging. My silverlight app has a situation where I actually open up another tab of the same project
Basically when I try to open another tab it just hangs after it starts opening the tab but never really finishes.

The tabs are the first thing that has brought this to my attention but I think maybe there is something wrong with the state of the browser, I can open the tools menu before I ever open up another tab and almost all options show up as grayed out

[image]

Its worth noting a couple things. This is only a problem when I'm debugging, and its reproducable (at random) by everyone on my team.

Comment: When you say you are debugging, do you mean your application has stopped at a breakpoint?  That is, are you doing step-by-step debugging?

Comment: debugging as in I would like to step into different pieces of the code but can't because I can't open up the tab to get where I need to. 

I'm attached to my silverlight process through visual studio

Comment: If you are doing step-by-step debugging your browser won't be fully functional since it is hosting your Silverlight app which you have halted the execution of.  For example, Google Chrome will tell you that the Silverlight plugin has stopped responding if you break for too long.

Comment: IF you are stopped on a break point I agree, but when just running most typicall browsing functions are not disabled, for example, that tools menu in the browser will be enabled.

Comment: Try [reseting IE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/internet-explorer/slow-five-tips-to-boost-performance).